# URL of the home page in Twig / OctoberCMS Template

Tags: twig, octobercms

So, I have this in my template code:

```
<div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-2"><a href="{{ '/' | page }}">HOME</a></div>
```

And it renders this:

```
<div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-2"><a href="">HOME</a></div>
```

How to you get it to render the URL for the home page (root default page)?

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the **name of the file** (without extensions) instead of the URL of the page.

For example, your page is `index.htm`, you should use the following code:

```
<div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-2"><a href="{{ 'index' | page }}">HOME</a></div>
```

*Source: [October Markup docs](http://octobercms.com/docs/markup/filter-page)*

For a file in a subdirectory, specify the directory. For the current page, use nothing inside `''`.

Answer (score 1):

In this use case, I think it makes sense to use the [|app](http://octobercms.com/docs/markup/filter-app) filter rather than |page.

```
<div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-2"><a href="{{ '/'|app }}">HOME</a></div>
```

Will give you what you want. And it will also protect you if you end up putting your site in a subdirectory.

Comment: This is wrong way of doing things in octobercms twig. you need to pass page name instead of url in page filter. 

This was the correct answer then
https://stackoverflow.com/a/32289296/5478697